# Unique Concatenate Data Frame Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have 365 CSV files representing mean values of unique sample locations. Each CSV file represents a different day. For example, my CSV files are listed as Day1.csv, Day2.csv, Day3.csv, and so on. I can import all CSVs in Python and use Pandas to convert them to dataframes and essentially append all 365 DFs into one long dataframe. Here is the long dataframe:

```
Location    MEAN    Day
A   0.2235  1
B   0.8215  1
C   0.0159  1
D   0.4259  1
A   0.5902  2
B   0.6201  2
C   0.0239  2
D   0.3021  2
A   0.7291  3
B   0.5022  3
C   0.0504  3
D   0.4982  3
```

....and so on....

The locations are constant.

What I want to do is take this very long appended DF (merged across 365 days), and concatenate the MEAN values sequentially by Location. I'd like to have the a new MEAN column that lists all the means by date, separated by commas (or some other delimitter). Essentially, this is what I want:

```
Location    MEAN
A   "0.2235, 0.5902, 0.7291"
B   "0.8215, 0.6201, 0.5022"
C   "0.0159, 0.0239, 0.0504"
D   "0.4259, 0.3021, 0.4982"
```

Where each Location is listed only once and all the MEANS are listed sequentially by day (Day1, Day2, ...so on...)

Here's the quick Python code I have to create the large merged DF:

```
combined_csv = pd.concat( [ pd.read_csv(f) for f in Files ] )
```

How can I build on this to produce the desired concatenated file with MEAN values listed sequentially by day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['Location','Day']).reset_index()
df1.groupby(['Location'])['MEAN'].apply(lambda x : ','.join(x))


Location
A    0.2235,0.5902,0.7291
B    0.8215,0.6201,0.5022
C    0.0159,0.0239,0.0504
D    0.4259,0.3021,0.4982
Name: MEAN, dtype: object
```

Comment: Wow, it's magic!  This is exactly what I was looking for, and it's only 2 lines of code. Amazing!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need just using `cumcount` get the 2nd lvl `merge` key , Based on you Files is ordered

```
combined_csv = pd.concat( [ pd.read_csv(f) for f in Files ],keys=np.arange(len(Files)) ).reset_index(level=0)


Longdf['level_0']=Loandf.groupby('Location').cumcount()

Longdf=Longdf.merge(combined_csv,on=['Location','level_0'],how='left').drop('level_0',1)
```